Is it a bad idea to take WFH on my birthday stating some other reason at my workplace?
Since I work as an analytical intern and have no other obligations other than finishing my daily goal of finishing my online coursework I am supposed to do, is it okay if I take WFH for my birthday and provide some other valid reason?
Context: As an intern, my only assigned task is to attend an online coursework meeting. Other than that, I have no other work.

Could you explain why you feel the need to lie about this? "It's my birthday, I fancied the day off".

Hey thanks for responding. I apologize for not phrasing the question better. It is just that I believe it might appear unprofessional.

But, just to confirm, you think lying about your reason is professional behaviour?

@Hardik - Everyone has a birthday. Celebrating your birthday is socially acceptable. Lying about leave is unprofessional, especially, if your taking off to celebrate your birthday.

Don't do that - having a birthday is not a free day. It looks that you are tuning your free days in your contract. If you want to do that, get a free day.

Do not get into the habit of lying about such things. If it is acceptable in your company to take work-from-home days, and if it is expected to provide an explanation, then it is your professional duty to provide a truthful explanation. If it is not required to provide an explanation, you might simply not give an explanation:

"I have some other things to do after work, and they are easier to reconcile with a full day of WFH than with a full day of office work plus the commute."

The one exception I would make is when there is something private you are entitled to keep secret, but even then I'd be as non-misleading as possible.

On a separate note, until Corona suddenly introduced home office, it was normal at my workplaces that employees with a birthday would bring a plate of donuts or the like for a slightly extended coffee break. Management approved of this "wasted time" because of the team-building benefits.
If something like that happens where you work, consider joining the tradition. It helps to make you part of the team.

It is also really silly to lie about something that is likely common knowledge. In a small company, everyone knows it's your birthday. In a big corporation, at least your teammates will know as well as your manager, who will see your lame excuse an immediately know what's going on.


is it okay if I take WFH for my birthday and provide some other valid
reason?

That depends entirely on the office culture. In some shops it would be fine. Not so in others.
If you are an intern and aren't familiar with the expectations in your office, you should err on the side of caution and not work from home.
Either way, you should not lie if required to state a reason for where you choose to work.

Honesty - That is the go to action.
Frankly, perhaps you might want to step back for a minute and consider why not being truthful would be a good option. Random internet people, I freaking hope, aren't going to suggest to someone that lying is the best course of action.
Most employers are actually humans, they will accomondate if asked.

If someone is going to downvote suggesting being honest, I would hope they would include a comment as to why.

I didn't downvote, but your first sentence can easily be misread as "Honestly, that is the go to action", where "that" doesn't refer to "Honesty" but to what the OP suggested, ie, lying. Then your whole post becomes "Random internet people won't openly suggest that lying is the best course of action, but honestly, it is"

@Stef I appreciate the feedback. Rereading my answer, I see how it could taken not quite how I meant.
